# Genexus AudioAPI on iOS

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I already implement the Genexus Audio API and it works for iOS including on background and when the screen locked, but when is in locked screen and the pause button is pressed the current playing is stopped instead pause and also for play again is need unlock the phone, this is the correctly behavior ?

Comment: in advanced I use the Ev3 U6 10.3.97697 with iOS 9.1.2

Comment: Probably not. We´ll take a look and let you know.

Comment: Hi Marcos you got check it ? Thx

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I didn't try it in Evo 3 yet, but I did try it in GeneXus Salto and is working as expected (pause and play in the lock screen continues where it left). Can you try in a newer version? Also, there have been may additions to the [AudioAPI in Salto](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30041,AudioAPI), you may want to check it out.